# Eval of ASP.Net is not using not equals

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to disable a div for db data value which fetched from code behind but how i can achieve with below Equals code

Requirement : Not Equal("1") then disable div.

my code is below : instead of Equals in below code ,I have to use not Equals.....

```
 <div class="row" style='<%# (Eval("Test").ToString().Equals("1"))? "display:none;" : string.Empty %>'>
```

Comment: You could switch the cases in your conditional so that it outputs `string.Empty` when the value equals "1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="row" style='<%= ((Test != "1") ? "display:none;" : string.Empty) %>'>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</h1>
</div>
```

assuming `Test` here, is an instance public property of type `string` in the code-behind of your page.

Or this could work too :

```
<div class="row" style='<%# ((Eval("Test").ToString() != "1") ? "display:none;" : string.Empty) %>'>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</h1>
</div>
```